# Constant value changing

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior

Suppose I have a struct definition:

```
struct thing
{
    thing* x;
    int z;

    thing() : x(this), z(0) {}
    void foo() const
    {
        this->x->z++;
    }
};
```

Note that I create a mutable pointer to myself (evil laugh)

And then I can use this later like this:

```
int main()
{
    const thing c;
    c.foo();
    assert(c.z == 1);
    c.foo();
    assert(c.z == 2);
    return c.z;
}
```

And as you can see it seems that I can change a constant value......is this UB?

Comment: Yes, it is UB, as `c` is const.

Comment: There is no general rule that says you can't subvert const without a cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[dcl.type.cv]p4:

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` ([dcl.stc]) can be
>   modified, any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr],
>   [expr.pre.incr]) a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its
>   lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior.

[basic.type.qualifier]p1:

> A *const object* is an object of type `const T` or a non-mutable subobject of such an object.

`c.z` is a const object, because it is a non-mutable subobject of `c`. Your code attempts to modify it during its lifetime. It follows that the code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `foo`-function itself would be OK, as `const` member functions like `T::foo() const` just indicate that `this` is of type `const *T`; The fact that a (non-const) member points to the same object is irrelevant then.

The object `c` in first place, however, is declared as const. So it is UB to alter the contents of `c` through whatever code, including the (per se correct) member function `foo`.

Comment: What about the fact that `c` is `const`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes; you may not change the value of `c->x`, but you may change the object referenced by `c->x`; so `c->x->z++` is valid even if `c` is const.

Comment: But since `c->x->z++` is `c.z++` isn't that UB?

Comment: I think under C++11 that is a violation of const-ness.  Pre-C++11, it's probably just being a bad agent.

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, I'm quite sure that it is not UB. `const` does not mean that the object is immutable in general; it just declares that it must not be changed through the (const) pointer at hand. So you cannot change `z` through a `(const*) this->z++`, but through another path to that object, i.e. through `this->x->z++`

Comment: Your example is only valid because `value` was not declared const in the first place.. but his `thing` instance is declared const.. and if you attempted to `const_cast<thing*>(this)->z++;` it'd be undefined behaviour.. So why would he be able to modify it through a shallow copy of `this`.. *Note:( I did not downvote.

Comment: @Brandon: Sh... Yes, you are right. I stuck to the `foo`-function itself, but ignored the fact that OPs `c` is const in first place.